# Should It is possible to update the same document twice using dls without conflicting update error in marklogic?

Tags: marklogic

Is It possible to update the same document twice using dls without conflicting update error in marklogic?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but not in the same transaction. Updates are gathered until all code has run, and committed together.

You may want to elaborate what you are trying to do, and what you have tried so far..

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

In the [Visibility of Updates](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/transactions#id_85012) section of the Application Developer's Guide, there is this note:

> An update statement cannot perform an update to a document that will conflict with other updates occurring in the same statement. For example, you cannot update a node and add a child element to that node in the same statement. An attempt to perform such conflicting updates to the same document in a single statement will fail with an XDMP-CONFLICTINGUPDATES exception.

In many cases, you can make more than one update, but those updates cannot conflict with each other.

If you show more information about what you're trying to accomplish, we can probably suggest a way to help.